# Why doesn't my type hint work when importing a value from another module?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

The first call to 'a' shows an error on Pycharm as expected but the second call does not, why?

my_file.py

```
from some_module import imported_val

def a(b: int):
    pass

val = 'something'
#Pyhcarm shows an error for this as expected
a(val)

#But for this it doens't
a(imported_val)
```

some_module.py

```
imported_val = 'something_else'
```

Even when I hover over imported_val in my_file.py, the tooltip correctly notes that it's a str

I tried invalidating cache on Pycharm, anything else I can attemp?

Comment: What type is `imported_val`? If it's `int`, then that's fine

Comment: What is `imported_val`? See how to create a [mcve] and [edit] the question.